# looking for directories with a year after 2000 in their names

Tags: regex, macos-catalina

I have a very long directory list that I need to find the ones newer than 2000. Problem is the folder date was not preserved so I have to go by directory name.

examples:

```
./aaa bbb aa ccc (1999)
./gggg rrr (1939)
./hhh bbb (2001)
```

I've try to come up with a regex for the name but I can't figure out what is wrong with it.... it's bring all foldes and I was expecting only 1 (in the example above)
`find -E . -regex '.*(20[0-9]{2})*' -type d`

then I have to move the 2000 and newer folders to another `tmp` folder...

any ideas how to do it?

Comment: do you know that `()` are regex meta characters that have to be escaped via ``\`` ?

Comment: ahhh.  awesome!!  escaping the parenthesis worked!!  :)

Comment: `20(?:[1-9][0-9]|0[1-9])` should match four-digit years between 2001 and 2099

Comment: A folder created in `1939` looks very interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regex, the parentheses are meta characters which are used for grouping and capturing. As to match a literal parenthesis, you have to escape it via backslash `\`.

Matching a parenthesized year between 2001 and 2099 is done by:

```regex
\(20(?:[1-9][0-9]|0[1-9])\)
```

The meta parentheses in the regular expression group the alternative patterns (indicated by pipe, `|`) of `[1-9][0-9]` (two-digit numbers starting with at least 1) and `0[1-9]` (1 to 9 with a leading zero). The `?:` after the opening parenthesis tells the regex engine that the group should not be captured.